# Why an external call using an interface reverts if an error occurs in the called function, but why it doesn't rever if it was made using the .call()?

Tags: solidity-0.8.x, interfaces, callcode

I was wondering what happens under the hood when a tx makes an external call using an interface compared to calling the exact same function but using the low-level call() function and the function's signature.

My question is, if an external call is made using an interface, why the entire tx is reverted if an error occurs in the called function?

And if the same function is called, but this time using the low-level call() and the function's signature, and the same error occurs, why on this scenario the entire the tx is not reverted, only the changes made on the called function are discarted and a "false" is returned to the caller, but the tx can continue its execution (if  the returned value is not validated)?

I was trying to find some documentation about it but got no luck with it.

I'm sharing an example of calling the same function using the two options I mentioned - interface and low-level call.
Context: The error is caused because the msg.sender has not enough allowance...

1.- **Using an interface**, if an error occurs in the first `transferFrom()`, the entire tx is reverted and the error msg is returned!

```
function swap(address from, address to, uint amount) public {
    ...
    IERC20(from).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
    IERC20(to).approve(address(this), swapAmount);
    IERC20(to).transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, swapAmount);
  }
```

2.- **Using the low-level call()** If an error occurs in the first `transferFrom()`, the changes made on that internal call are reverted, but the tx execution continues on the swap() function and the last two lines are executed...

```
function swapUsingCallOpcode(address from, address to, uint amount) public {
    ...
    from.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("transferFrom(address,address,uint256)", msg.sender, address(this), amount));
    // Even though the above call fails, these two lines will be executed!
    IERC20(to).approve(address(this), swapAmount);
    IERC20(to).transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, swapAmount);
  }
```

**I'm trying to understand why this happens, not how to prevent it**

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a call reverts within the EVM, it doesn't revert the entire transaction. It just pushes a true/false `success` value onto the stack for the context calling it to decide what to do.

Solidity is meant to add safety on top of using the EVM directly, so when you call a function properly (in your example, using the interface), it validates that `success` value, and if it's false, it will automatically revert. When you do a low level `.call` in Solidity, the compiler doesn't do that automatically for you. Instead it just gives you the value of `success` for you to decide what to do with it.

Comment: Your answer makes absolute sense, probably I misunderstood the behavior of what happens when an error happens in a message call, now I see the why.

Just wondering if this applies also to internal calls?
I know internal calls are made by executing a jump instead of an actual call, but, what would happen if the internal call faces an error, same thing?

Comment: @StalinMacias Since jumps don't create a call frame, it would revert to the last call. So if A called B, and B did an internal call which reverted, the entire call to B would be reverted and A would get that success/false value on the stack